# Search Value from JSON in C++

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I want to search argv[2] value in JSON but i couldn't do this. I looked the other threads but they couldn't hep either. Because i am a newbie. So ho can I do this?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <json/json.h>
#include <json/value.h>

using namespace std;

// struct instead of class
struct Element {
    int atomNumber;
    string atomName;
    string atomSymbol;
    string atomType;
    string atomSerie;

// void funciton instead of Book(){}
    void printinfo() {
        cout << "Atom Number: " << atomNumber << "\n";
        cout << "Atom name: " << atomName << "\n";
        cout << "Atom Symbol: " << atomSymbol << "\n";
        cout << "Atom Type: " << atomType << "\n";
        cout << "Atom Serie: " << atomSerie << "\n";
    }
};

//         Arg Count      Args
//            V            V
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Json::Value ptable;
    std::ifstream ptable_file("ptable.json", std::ifstream::binary);
    ptable_file >> ptable;  

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "-p") == 0){
        
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What JSON library are you using?jsoncpp

Comment: You should check argc value, the array size, before accessing values of the array argv.

Comment: @balping yes, jsoncpp.